# Flutter: personalized AppBar with flexibleSpace with round edges don't workas intended

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have the two following pieces of code, and the content of body when scrolled clip in a bad way to the AppBar, I aim to have the edge as the edges of the image and not as a rectangle.

```
Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: kColorBg,
        extendBody: true,
        extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
        appBar: kAppBar("Pagamenti"),
        body: const SafeArea(child: Body()),
        // floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(onPressed: _onPressed, backgroundColor: kColorLogo, child: const Icon(Icons.add, size: kRadiusPicture,)),
      ),
```

```
AppBar kAppBar(String title) {
double fontSize = 26.0;
double x = 160.0;
double y = 35.0;
  return AppBar(
    centerTitle: true,
    toolbarHeight: 100,
    flexibleSpace: ClipRRect(
      clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(bottomLeft: Radius.elliptical(x, y), bottomRight: Radius.elliptical(x, y)),
      child: Container(
        height: 200,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(bottomLeft: Radius.elliptical(x, y), bottomRight: Radius.elliptical(x, y)),
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage(R.pngImages.illustrazione_interna),
            fit: BoxFit.fill,
            colorFilter: const ColorFilter.mode(kColorPrimary, BlendMode.dstATop)
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
    elevation: 0,
    title: Text(title, style: TextStyle(fontSize: fontSize, color: kColorWhite, fontFamily: 'Roboto', fontWeight: FontWeight.w700)),
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(bottomLeft: Radius.elliptical(x, y), bottomRight: Radius.elliptical(x, y))
    ),
    shadowColor: Colors.red,
    foregroundColor: Colors.white,
    backgroundColor: Colors.red,
  );
}
```

[image: Screenshot 1]
[image: Screenshot 2]

Sorry for the bad english, and thank you for your time.

EDIT:
If I set to Colors.transparent both scaffold and the appbar a have this.
[image]

Comment: Have you tried to remove or set to transparent the color properties of the AppBar? Like:     
    ```shadowColor: Colors.transparent,
    foregroundColor: Colors.transparent,
    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,```

Comment: Yes, I tried and it works the same as the screenshots, I even changed the image to make it round as the container but it doesn't seem to wokr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you try to set background transparent yet?

UPDATE: Accepted in comment below

```dart
Scaffod(
  ...
  backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
  appbar: AppBar(
    ...
    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
    elevation: 0.0,
    ...
  ),
  body: Container(
    color: Colors.red, // <your body color>,
    ...
  ),
  ...
)
```

Comment: Yes, I tried, I edit the main post to show you the difference, but it still doesn't work

Comment: Can you try move `SafeArea` from body to outside of `Scaffold`?

Comment: It worked, I added an asnwer with the solution, thank you

Answer (score 2):

To resolve the issue try to remove Appbar and use another widget of your choice using Column, which might help you to create the Customised Appbar

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the usage of `SafeArea`, if you remove it from before the `body` it will work.